# Apigility rest service - how to filter by a non unique column using db connected

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I have a db-connected `rest` service, and I only managed to so far get the full collection from the `database` or a single entity by its `ID`.

I can't find a proper guide to explain how to use the `GET` url parameters to filter by other fields, and how do I choose for example whether its "LIKE" or LIKE %%" or other operators for that matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my experience with CodeConnected Services.  YMMV..

**Retrieving URL Parameters - Controller/Resource class.**

Your controller needs to retrieve them from the `$this->getEvent()`

```
 /**
 * Fetch a single Entity by ID, with some Query Params
 */
public function fetch($entity_id)
{
    // retrieve the query parameters\
    $queryParams = $this->getEvent()->getQueryParams();
}
```

Secondly , only parameters approved on your module.config.php will make it past the validator/filter part of Apigility.  Notice Collection Query Whitelist

`module.config.php` inside your service's module folder

```
'ServiceName\\V1\\Rest\\ServiceName\\Controller' => array(
            ...
            'entity_http_methods' => array(
                0 => 'GET',
                1 => 'PATCH',
                2 => 'PUT',
                3 => 'DELETE',
            ),
            'collection_http_methods' => array(
                0 => 'GET',
                1 => 'POST',
            ),
            'collection_query_whitelist' => array(
                0 => 'username',
                1 => 'entity_provider',
                2 => 'entity_type',
                3 => 'entity_date_range',
                4 => 'sort_by',
                5 => 'sort_order'
            ),
            ...
```

Comment: Testing it, let me get back to you on that

Comment: Oh yes, I actually found out that Apigility editor lets you whitelist these parameters through its editor.

Once I whitelist a param it does exactly what you wrote over here. Then again I wanted to do it in a db-connected and not in a code connected... and even though I did move to code connected it still does not really answer the question does it?

Ill mark it anyway.

Comment: sorry I can't help with DB-Connected, I rarely (never, except in a tutorial) use them.

Comment: Don't be! You still helped me in a way to aim me towards what I need.